# How Do I translate an Angular Electron App

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, translation, electron-packager

I'm trying to translate a en-us (United States English) Angular Electron app to es-419 (Latin American Spanish), but I can't seem to find any information on the Electron documentation on how to go about this.

What is the most common/popular way to internationalize Angular+Electron apps?

I had assumed this would just be done following the instructions found within the angular documentation, so I followed the instructions provided on their site, but I couldn't figure out how to point the electron compiler to a specific distribution of my app.

If I try to give win.loadURL() the direct path to a specific index.html within a language specific dist folder, the project would run but nothing would render.  I suspect it wasn't detecting any .js files because the dev console would produce errors saying such.

```js
 win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/app-name/es-419/index.html`); // Load the index.html of the app.
```

But if I would run the app with localization set to false, the application would run as expected without issue by only changing the win.LoadURL() to

```js
 win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/app-name/index.html`); // Load the index.html of the app.
```

Of course, without need for separate localization folders in my "dist" folder I'm able to just call the index file inside "app-name".

The translations do not need to be dynamic (I can have completely separate .exe files for both English and Spanish), but due to the size of this app I don't want to maintain two separate code versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Transloco to translate my whole app, I couldn't get anything else to work. If you just manually set a language at the beginning screen, your whole app will be translated.